# Android: show gradient like shadow using shape.xml

Tags: android, xml, gradient, android-drawable

Hi I am trying to get shadow like gradient only on the top using the shape.xml

[image]

From the image am wrapping the buttons in a linear layout and I want to give the gradient on top of the layout.

Am doing as below but it is not working out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#f0f0f0" />
            <solid android:color="#f0f0f0" />

        </shape>
   </item>

   <item android:top="1dp"> 
      <shape 
        android:shape="line">
       <gradient

        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#000000" />
        </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 18):

No need to use Layer-list , You can do it by `Gradient`. Try this flowing code ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#b4909090" android:endColor="#b4fafafa" android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Change the `startColor` and `endColor` as you want. And the result is ->

[image: Image For Shadow]

Comment: that code is giving gradient to whole linear layout..just want a line to the layout

Comment: You didn't specify how to use this. This is valid if you have an `ImageView` above  your view and set this as background to the `ImageView`. When you apply this as background to the `LinearLayout` entire view will have gradient background. He wants his background to be white with a gradient border on top.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient 
  android:type="linear"
  android:centerX="78%" 
  android:startColor="#FFf7f7f7" 
  android:centerColor="#FFC0C0C0" 
  android:endColor="#FFbebebe" 
  android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```